# Set Sidebar Color in Beamer Class (using xelatex)

Tags: beamer, xetex, color

I'd like to change the color of beamer sidebar, however I don't know which parameter `\setbeamercolor{}{}` wants for the sidebar color. I'm using `\usepackage{xcolor}` and specify my own colors like that: `\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{45,170,250}`.

My tex compiler is `xelatex`

Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                          

% beamer theme                                                                  
\usetheme{Marburg}                                                              

% german spelling                                                               
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                                             

% set font encoding                                                             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        

% math stuff                                                                    
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                            
\usepackage{amsfonts}                                                           
\usepackage{amssymb}                                                            

% color                                                                         
\usepackage{xcolor}                                                             

% set font to Helvetica Light                                                   
\usepackage{xltxtra}                                                            
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica Light}                                    

\title{Präsentation}                                                            
\author{Max Mustermann}                                                         
\date{\today}                                                                   

% removes navigation bar                                                        
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty                                           

\begin{document}                                                                

\begin{frame}                                                                   
    \frametitle{Ein Demotitel}                                                  
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz äöüß 1234567890                                  
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ                                                  
\end{frame}                                                                     

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know which `beamer` colors are used in certain theme, look at its definition style file, `beamerthemeMarsburg.sty` in this case. There you will see:

```
\mode<presentation>

\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt]{sidebar}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{parent=palette primary}

{\usebeamercolor{palette quaternary}}
{\usebeamercolor{palette primary}}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}[vertical shading][top=palette quaternary.bg,bottom=palette primary.bg]
```

which means that this theme uses color theme `whale` and that `sidebar` has a `vertical shading` based in colors `palette quaternary.bg` and `palette primary.bg`.

Now you have two possibilities, change `palette` definitions or just change `sidebar` definition. You must use the first one in case you want to be sure that every template based on this color is also change. If you just want to change sidebar background it's enough to add

```
\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{45,170,250}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}[vertical shading][top=palette quaternary.bg,bottom=myBlue]
\makeatother
```

in your preamble. Of course, if your side bar is on the left, change `right` by `left`. 
The result looks like:

[image]

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                          

% beamer theme                                                                  
\usetheme{Marburg}                                                              

% german spelling                                                               
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                                             

% set font encoding                                                             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        

% math stuff                                                                    
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                            
\usepackage{amsfonts}                                                           
\usepackage{amssymb}                                                            

% color                                                                         
%\usepackage{xcolor}                                                             

% set font to Helvetica Light                                                   
\usepackage{xltxtra}                                                            
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Tahoma}                                    

\title{Präsentation}                                                            
\author{Max Mustermann}                                                         
\date{\today}                                                                   

% removes navigation bar                                                        
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty                                           

\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{45,170,250}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}[vertical shading][top=palette quaternary.bg,bottom=myBlue]
\makeatother

\begin{document}                                                                

\begin{frame}                                                                   
    \frametitle{Ein Demotitel}                                                  
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz äöüß 1234567890                                  
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ                                                  
\end{frame}                                                                     

\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. I've used Tahoma font instead of original Helvetica Light.
2. `beamer` already load `xcolor`, you can delete `\usepackage{xcolor}` from your preamble.

Result of `\listfiles` command

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion 332bfd3ce558)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/12/25 (rcs-revision 31cc758a62ae)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2014/04/28 v4.01 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2011/12/02 v1.10 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2011/12/02 v1.10 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 72f39e01808a)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2013/10/02  (rcs-revision cdc8e9a3aaac)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2013/05/23  (rcs-revision 0fdf5bc43be8)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2013/10/05  (rcs-revision 62be157fe783)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2013/10/15  (rcs-revision 65cb471f9634)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerthemeMarburg.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemesidebar.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 english.ldf    2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
ngermanb.ldf    2008/07/06 v2.6n new German support from the babel system
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 xltxtra.sty    2010/09/20 v0.5e Improvements for the "XeLaTeX" format
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/05/06 v4751 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2014/05/06 v4751 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  xparse.sty    2014/05/05 v4740 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fixltx2e.sty    2014/04/27 v1.1p fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
fontspec.cfg
realscripts.sty    2013/03/18 v0.3c Access OpenType subscripts and superscripts

metalogo.sty    2010/05/29 v0.12 Extended TeX logo macros
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it shows me the same color as before. I pasted the code just before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @konze I've included the complete code I've used to produce the example. Please test it and let me know if it's still wrong.

Comment: Thank you, however this also doesn't work.

Comment: @konze. Did you test with my complete example or did you included new lines into your code? Did you test my code with another bottom color? Did you delete your .pdf file before testing? Did you look into *.log file? Please provide some more details because I cannot imagin what happens.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I copied your whole example into a new clean file. I tested it with another bottom color twice (first: `\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{255,0,0}`, second: `\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}[vertical shading][top=palette quaternary.bg,bottom=red]`. I deleted the old pdf file before every test. In the log file are only warnings like `LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"... Redefining document command ...`

Comment: @Konze I don't understand what's wrong. Please, include `\listfiles` command right before `\begin{document}` and compare the result (in *.log file) with the list I've included in my answer.

Comment: the first thing I recognized was that I have a lot of outdated versions of files/packages. Currently I'm running TeX Live for updates.

Comment: Updating my TeX distro solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your help!